# What are the up-to-date results on explicit lower bounds for $\Sigma_2$ communication complexity?

Tags: communication-complexity, polynomial-hierarchy

What are the best polylogarithmic lower bounds known for $\Sigma_2$-communication complexity on an explicit function? Are there any known candidate functions for $O(n^\epsilon)$ communication complexity? The only results I am aware of are of the negative type, with Katz and independently Hambardzumyan, Hatami, and Ndiaye both finding a counterexample to Problem 4.9 in Jukna's *Boolean Function Complexity*, which would have implied polynomial $\Sigma_2$ communication bounds.

Answer (score 3):

This paper by Lokam shows a lower bound of $3\log n$ on the $\Sigma_2$-communication complexity of inner product and related functions:
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Graph-Complexity-and-Slice-Functions-Lokam/fc82031341bd6284175b852f90d53557dd8311f7

The paper is phrased in terms of graph complexity, and therefore states the lower bound as $\log^3 n$, but this corresponds to $3\log n$ for communication complexity.

I am not aware of stronger lower bounds.